# Virgin Atlantic JFK Clubhouse Access

Tags: layovers, jfk, lounges, virgin-atlantic

I'll be flying from London to Las Vegas, via JFK bought on Virgin Atlantic. I'm flying Upper Class from LHR to JFK, and Delta business from JFK to LAS. It's all under the same Virgin Atlantic booking.

I arrive in JFK at ~11pm. And the flight out the next morning is at ~10am. The Virgin Clubhouse at JFK opens at 4am, and I would like to use it to freshen up etc.

Will I get Clubhouse access, given the JFK-LAS flight is a) domestic and b) technically not on the same day as the international leg of the journey.